# Collection <__NSSetM: 0x14ea0160> was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: ios

When I use the UICollectionView. I need change it's dataArray and reloadData.  But when I delete one of the object in the dataArray, then I write the code [collectionView reloadData];,I slide the collectionView then the error comes , Tell me that      *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSSetM: 0x14ea0160> was mutated while being enumerated.'   How can i resolve this problem? Thank you very much!!!

```
NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.dataArray]; 
for (Mysource *source in self.dataArray) { 
    if (source.isSelect) { 
        [temp removeObject:source]; 
    } 
} 
self.dataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:temp]; 
[self.CollectionView reloadData];
```

Comment: You need to show your code or no-one can help you.

Comment: NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.dataArray];
        for (Mysource *source in self.dataArray) {
            if (source.isSelect) {
                [temp removeObject:source];
            }
        }
        
        self.dataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:temp];

 [self.CollectionView reloadData];

Comment: it not crash Immediately， When I do this ,Then i slide the CollectionView ,It will crash

Comment: That is not the code that's causing the problem.  The error message shows that an `NSMutableSet` is being mutated.  That's what the `NSSetM` indicates. You need to look elsewhere.  First of all, make sure that this is happening on the main thread, because all UI calls must happen on the main thread, and that includes `UICollectionView.reloadData`

Answer (score -1):

I believe, when you are enumerating through some Collection (a loop probably), you are removing an object from that Collection inside the loop. Something like the following:

```
for (id object in someArray)
   if (conditionSatisfied)
       [someArray removeObject:object];
```

This is not allowed in Objective-C. You need to store the objects you need to remove in a temp Collection and then remove it after the loop ends.

Comment: But i have copy the dataArray, in the for in, I have not changed the dataArray, i just change the temp.  And when i do this ,it will not crash immdiately.  i slide the CollectionView ,It will crash.

Comment: As was pointed out by Ewan Mellor, the code you have shown is not where the exception occurs, because it doesn't have an NSMutableSet - Set an exception breakpoint in Xcode and see where the crash is actually occurring

Comment: thank you ,I have set the All Exceptions ,but it breaks in the appDelegate . And i have not writed any code about NSMutableSet .

Comment: I wrote this too soon I guess. You did not share your code at that time. Can you share your stack trace when this error occurs?